# Zend Framework multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm currently using only one database with Zend Framework, but now I have to add ONE MORE.

I'm using this code right now:

```
public static function setupDatabase()
{
    $config = self::$registry->configuration;
    $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db->adapter, $config->db->toArray());
    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    self::$registry->database = $db;
    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
}
```

What code do I need to write in order to use ONE MORE database; and how I will reference it, when I need to make some queries or so..

Comment: Take a look at this article for some ideas: http://www.amazium.com/blog/zendapplication-multiple-databases

Comment: If one of the answers helped you Uffo, you should mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my situation, I have a 'core' database that loads customer info, including the customer's database connection info.  The core connection settings are in the `application.ini`.  All the code below is in my bootstrap.

Loading 'core' connection (not set to default in `ini`):

```
$db_core = $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
$db_core->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
Zend_Registry::set('db_core', $db_core);
```

After settings are loaded from 'core' database into the registry:

```
$settings = Zend_Registry::get('settings');
$db = Zend_Db::factory(
    $settings->db_adapter,
    array(
        'host' => $settings->db_host,
        'username' => $settings->db_user,
        'password' => $settings->db_pass,
        'dbname' => $settings->db_name,
    )
);
$db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

Answer (score 21):

This is included in the framework as [`Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb).

Comment: I was not aware of this one, I'll have to look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

place something like in your application.ini

```
  [production]

  resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "pdo_mysql"

  resources.multidb.db1.host = "localhost"

  resources.multidb.db1.username = "webuser"

  resources.multidb.db1.password = "XXXX"

  resources.multidb.db1.dbname = "db1"



  resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "pdo_pgsql"

  resources.multidb.db2.host = "example.com"

  resources.multidb.db2.username = "dba"

  resources.multidb.db2.password = "notthatpublic"

  resources.multidb.db2.dbname = "db2"

  resources.multidb.db2.default = true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you

In applocation.ini file

```
resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.db1.host    = "localhost"
resources.multidb.db1.username  = "root"
resources.multidb.db1.password  = ""
resources.multidb.db1.dbname   = "db1"
resources.multidb.db1.charset = "utf8"
resources.multidb.db1.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
resources.multidb.db1.default = true

resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.db2.host = "localhost"
resources.multidb.db2.username = "root"
resources.multidb.db2.password = ""
resources.multidb.db2.dbname   = "db2"
resources.multidb.db2.charset = "utf8"
resources.multidb.db2.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
resources.multidb.db2.default  = false
```

in bootstrap file

```
protected function _initDbAdaptersToRegistry()
{
    $this->bootstrap('multidb');
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');

    $Adapter1 = $resource->getDb('db1');
    $Adapter2 = $resource->getDb('db2');     
    Zend_Registry::set('db1', $Adapter1);
    Zend_Registry::set('db2',$Adapter2);
}
```

more description on http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/10/multiple-database-zend-framework